# NullReferenceException with simple textView Xamarin android c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am working on the following code for practicing purposes:

```
namespace HeerlenMurals
{
class dialog_locationInfo : DialogFragment
{
    TextView routeName;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.selectRouteDialogLayout, container, false);
        routeName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.locationName);

        routeName.Text = "hello";

        return view;
    }

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle); // Makes title bar invisible
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
}
```

When I run this, I get a nullreferenceexception when it tries to add "Hello" as text to the textView "routeName".

I can't see why this is occuring, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `view` returned by your `inflater` returning a `view` that contains the `TextView`?

Comment: Damn! I used the wrong layout for the view! Copy pasted this from another fragment activity and forgot to change that. Stupid me. It works, sorry for the hassle.